# How does the partial pressure of oxygen affect mental focus?

Tags: respiration, cognition

[On this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoxia_(medical)%23Signs_and_symptoms) it says that lower oxygen levels can cause light-headedness. Is there evidence that higher partial pressure of oxygen can *improve* mental focus?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Seems like the whole question is about the definitions of percentage and concentration. This question doesn't appear to be about biology. You probably read a text somewhere which talk about precentage of oxygen in the air and concentration (of oxygen I would assume) in the air that was unclear to you. If this is the case, you should include your passage and explain what you don't understand.

Comment: @Remi.b I mean concentration as in focus. If biology.SE isn't the right place for this question, please guide me.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Ok. Your question is on-topic! I retracted my close vote. Where did you read that lower concentration in oxygen decreases abilities to focus on a task? It will probably help having the reference.

Comment: please rephrase your question, maybe expand a little. Maybe include some reference to what to talk about. Otherwise it is hard to understand

Comment: @Remi.b well I thought it was well-known, but when I went looking for it, it was harder to find than anticipated. Edited my question with a source.

Comment: Vrwim: I made a pretty significant edit to try to avert the VTC. I *think* you’re asking about altitude (which is the most common situation where inspired O2 is compromised), but that does not affect the *percentage* of O2 but rather atmospheric pressure--> partial pressure of O2. I also rephrased it so it seemed clearer to me. Please feel free to roll back whatever you don’t like.

Comment: I know that it compromises concentration, I am asking about whether higher levels of oxygen improve concentration.

Comment: Vrwim, sorry I misunderstood. I just re-edited, but feel free to restate it however you’d like.

Comment: @Susan this is great! Couldn't have said it better myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long term exposure to hyperoxia actually does more harm than good. Though short term hyperoxia is recommended after brain injuries (http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/741751_3) as a valid clinical strategy.

For lower concentrations of oxygen, there seems to be evidence that cognitive function is improved:

[image: External oxygen administration has been shown to have positive effects on memory formation (Moss & Scholey, 1996; Scholey, Moss, Neave, & Wesnes, 1999). Reaction time is faster with external oxygen administration when responding to previously presented words (Scholey et al., 1999). Oxygen administration has been found to improve aspects of everyday memory, including remembering shopping list items and matching names to faces (Winder & Borrill, 1998). Positive effects on the visuospatial cognitive performance of administration of highly concentrated oxygen resulted from an increase in cerebral activation and a decrease in cerebral lateralization (Chung, Tack, Kim, Lee, & Sohn, 2004). | Not all cognitive measures are improved by oxygen administration. For example, the level of working memory on a computerized test was unaffected by oxygen administration (Moss, Scholey, & Wesnes, 1998; Scholey, Moss, & Wesnes, 1998). Induced hyperoxia had no effect on forward or backward digit span performance (Scholey et al., 1998). Andersson, Berggren, Gronkvist, Magnusson, and Svensson (2002) observed that working memory, long-term memory, and prospective memory were not affected by oxygen inhalation.]

You can read more about that here: *Chung, Soon-Cheol, et al. "Effect of 30% oxygen administration on verbal cognitive performance, blood oxygen saturation and heart rate." Applied psychophysiology and biofeedback 31.4 (2006): 281-293.*

And also this:

> This study aimed to investigate whether inhalation
>   of the air with 30% oxygen compared with normal air
>   enhances cognitive functioning through increased activation in
>   the brain. The verbal and visuospatial tasks were performed
>   while brain images were scanned. The results showed that
>   there were improvements in performance and also increased
>   activation in several brain areas under the condition of 30%
>   oxygen. These results suggest that a higher concentration of
>   the inhaled oxygen increases the saturation of the blood
>   oxygen in the brain, and facilitates cognitive performance.

Taken from: *Sohn, Jin-Hun, Soon-Cheol Chung, and Eun-Hye Jang. "30% oxygen inhalation enhances cognitive performance through robust activation in the brain." Journal of physiological anthropology and applied human science 24.1 (2005): 51-53.*

Though you have to be a bit careful about oxygen poisoning.

> While oxygen is an essential component for living organisms, the
>   formation of reactive O<sub>2</sub> intermediates is commonplace in aerobically
>   metabolizing cells. The stability of a variety of reactive O<sub>2</sub>
>   intermediates varies, but in some instances their interaction with the
>   intracellular environment sets the basis for the pathophysiology of
>   several disease states.

Adapted from: *Cadenas, Enrique. "Biochemistry of oxygen toxicity." Annual review of biochemistry 58.1 (1989): 79-110.*

[image]

> Pathophysiological processes are associated with increased levels of
>   hyperoxia-induced reactive O<sub>2</sub> species (ROS) which may readily react
>   with surrounding biological tissues, damaging lipids, proteins, and
>   nucleic acids. Protective antioxidant defenses can become overwhelmed
>   with ROS leading to oxidative stress.
>
> The continuous exposure of newborn rats to 70–80 per cent oxygen at atmospheric pressure throughout the first 9 days of life significantly inhibited the growth of the brain which normally occurs during this period of life. The accumulations of DNA, RNA, total protein, and proteolipid protein which accompany brain growth during this period were all approximately proportionately depressed by the oxygen-enriched atmosphere. RNA/DNA and protein/DNA ratios were unaffected. The increase in brain mass in the first week of life reflects mainly cell proliferation, and since the decreased DNA accumulation occurred with no changes in RNA/DNA and protein/DNA ratios, we conclude that the effect of oxygen was to inhibit cellular division. We estimate that the oxygen exposure caused an approximately 7 per cent deficit in the cell population of the brain. These results indicate that the use of elevated concentrations of oxygen may have serious deleterious effects on the growth and development of the brain.

Taken from:* Grave, G. D., C. Kennedy, and L. Sokoloff. "Impairment of growth and development of the rat brain by hyperoxia at atmospheric pressure." Journal of neurochemistry 19.1 (1972): 187-194.*

Also hydrogen peroxide is  produced:

> Thus the H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> concentration in brains of rats exposed to room air is calculated to be about 7.7 pM, rises 60% when O<sub>2</sub> tension is increased to 100% O<sub>2</sub>, and increases 300% at 3 ATA 100% O<sub>2</sub>, where symptoms of central nervous system toxicity first become apparent. These studies support the concept that H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> is an important mediator of O<sub>2</sub>-induced injury to the central nervous system.

Taken from: *Yusa, T. O. S. H. I. K. O., et al. "Hyperoxia increases H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> production by brain in vivo." Journal of Applied Physiology 63.1 (1987): 353-358.*

You can also always read the wiki page for oxygen poisoning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity and also hyperoxia itself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoxia

Comment: Okay, what do about slightly higher percentages? Like 25-30?

Comment: @vrwim answer edited.

Comment: that is what I was looking for! Thanks! I will look at the references in there and read up on that some more.